# Traversing through an object and maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, json

I am trying to read content of a file which is structured like [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vxApW5KW9A82Vxv_JSCwiFAAWPNjrpcj)

When I am getting the object I tried to find its nested property name ErrorCode. but the function fetch_property always returns undefined.

Here is the function

```
read_content = (path) => {
    fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function (error, data) {
        json_data = data
        // console.log(data)
        data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
        tem_data = data
        // Object.keys(data).forEach(key => console.log(key))
        // tem_data = data['Response']['Error']
        let result = fetch_property(data, "ErrorCode");
        console.log(result)
    })
}

fetch_property = (obj, property) => {
    if (obj[property] == property) {
        return obj[property]
    } else {
        for (let i in obj) {
            let found_label = fetch_property(obj[i], property)
            if (found_label) return found_label
        }

    }
}
```

How do I get the value of property ErrorCode from the content that is returned from the readFile function?

I just found out that the typeof data is still a string even after using JSON.parse. Why it was not converted to an object?

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems with your code. First, you don't need `JSON.stringify`. `JSON.parse` is enough. Second, your if statement `if (obj[property] == property)` doesn't work. You should first iterate through all item's properties. Here is a working example:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('temp.json', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    var json = JSON.parse(data);

    var result = fetch_property(json, "ErrorCode");
    console.log(result)
});

fetch_property = (obj, property) => {
    for (var item in obj) {
        if (item == property)
            return obj[item];

        if (typeof obj[item] == "object") {
            var result = fetch_property(obj[item], property);

            if (typeof result != "undefined")
                return result;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: One may also directly [`require`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_id) JSON files instead of manually reading them. ;)

Comment: Alternatively, instead of iterating through all keys from the beginning, the first if statement could be `if (property in obj) return obj[property]`. That would save a lot of looping...